# How get one record per each hundred of records?

Tags: python, mysql, database, sqlalchemy

I have ten thousands records in table. For one of cases, I have to get only one record per each hundred of records. What should I do?

I read about `SET`/`OFFSET` and `LIMIT`. I thought about something like :

```
def get_one_paczka_per_n_paczek(db: Session, sesja_id: int, per_n: int):
    liczba = 0
    lista = []
    while True:
        print(f"liczba elementów {len(lista)}")
        element = db.query(PaczkaDanych).offset(liczba).first()
        print(element)
        if element is not None:
            lista.append(element)
        else:
            break
        liczba = liczba + per_n
    return lista
```

Maybe something smarter exists than `LIMIT` and `SET` in a loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your table has an integer primary key that autoincrements by 1 then you could return the rows where `MOD(id, 100)` equals `1`:

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa

paczka = sa.Table("paczka", sa.MetaData(), autoload_with=engine)

with engine.connect() as conn:
    results = conn.execute(
        sa.select(paczka).where(sa.func.mod(paczka.c.id, 100) == 1)
    ).fetchall()
```

That won't necessarily be perfect because autoincrement columns are not guaranteed to be perfectly sequential (i.e., there may be gaps in the values) but it may be "close enough" depending on your specific task.